# Black screen after install....

Tags: installation

I did a clean install of Ubuntu on my PC, but after restarting my screen is just black and has been for about two hours now... Any ideas to help me with this? I installed the 64-bit version on a p4 3.2ghz machine with 4gb of ram... Should I try the 32-bit? Or is it something deeper maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking inside you computer, or at the plugs. plugs may not be connected correctly, and if they are Try reconnecting your video card